# Merging subunits and disputed territories in D3/SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, dictionary, d3.js, topojson

I have a Json file that includes subunits and disputed areas from the continent of Africa.  The two disputed areas in question are Morocco and Western Sahara.  Basically, I want to merge Western Sahara into the disputed area currently owned by Morroco so that it all encompasses Western Sahara.

I saw the Merging States example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5416405) (topojson.merge), but I can't quite figure out how to adapt it to my situation.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
d3.json("Scripts/D3/africa.json", function (error, africa) {

        g.selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(africa, africa.objects.subunits).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function (d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
            .attr("data-map-id", function (d) { return d.properties.fips; })
            .attr("data-region", function (d) { return d.properties.region; })
            .attr("d", path)
            .on("click", clicked);

        g.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.mesh(africa, africa.objects.subunits, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
            .attr("class", "mesh")
            .attr("d", path);

        g.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.feature(africa, africa.objects.disputed_areas))
            .attr("class", "disputedarea")
            .on("click", clicked);

        g.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.mesh(africa, africa.objects.disputed_areas))
            .attr("class", "mesh")
            .attr("d", path);
```

Comment: You put the IDs of the objects you want to merge into `selected`.

Comment: Thanks, Lars.  I have an 'africa.objects.subunits' object and an 'africa.objects.disputed_areas' object, both with the same ID ("#SAH").  So I'm not sure how to filter on those two disparate types.  Any further help is much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds to me like you would need to draw only one of them and do the merging there.